# text and image overlap?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WWnq.png)

```
a += '<a href="' + data.response.lst[i].url + '" > <img src="/img/Group 600.svg" /> <span style=" font-size: 12px;color: #094A98;  font-weight: 700;font-family: open sans;   padding-left: 12px; word-break: break-word;"> ' + data.response.lst[i].display_Name + '</span></a>'
```

i have created drop down under which  text and image is shown , but when text length is maximum , it display at bottom of image, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in a div and separate out the child elements.

I have styled parent div with `display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap;` but you could also do it by assigning the child elements with `display:inline-block;`

```
a += '<a href="' + data.response.lst[i].url + '" ><div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap;"><div><img src="/img/Group 600.svg" /></div><div><span style=" font-size: 12px;color: #094A98;  font-weight: 700;font-family: open sans;   padding-left: 12px; word-break: break-word;"> ' + data.response.lst[i].display_Name + '</span></div></div></a>'
```